# Convert WAV to FLAC in FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

How can I convert a WAV file to an FLAC file with FFmpeg?

I need to make various files. One in 16 Bit, one in 24 bit, and one in 32 [bit depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth).

I also need to make different [sample rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate). E.g one in 176,400 kHz and one in 44,100 kHz.

I know `FFmpeg -i input-file.wav output-file.flac` will convert the file but I am not sure about the rest.

The FFmpeg documentation (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/flac_8h.html) is not very helpful with this.

Answer (score 31):

FFmpeg's FLAC encoder supports sample bit depths of 16 and 24 bits, the latter padded to 32-bit. So for 24-bit, you will have to use a filter in-between.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af aformat=s32:176000 out.flac
```

The above encodes to a 176 kHz 24-bit sample, stored as 32-bits. And the command below encodes to 16-bit and 44.1 kHz.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af aformat=s16:44100 out.flac
```

Comment: For anyone reading this answer later, "16 and 24 bit samples" is referring to "Bit Depth", as opposed to "Bit Rate". "Bit Depth" is sometimes also referred to (By VLC for example) as "Bits per Sample".

Comment: Thanks, with your help I was able to transform an MP3 that I got from YouTube to use it in a synthesizer that only allows files in 16 bits and 44.1 Khz

Comment: Does bit depth conversion affect quality lossy?

Comment: From higher to lower, mathematically yes, perceptually, not really unless it's extreme.